# Showing that $u(0)=mu(1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $m \neq 1$ and the space:

$$U = \{ u \in H^1(0,1) \mid u(0) = mu(1) \}$$

In trying to show that this is a closed subspace of $H^1(0,1)$, which is the sobolev space $W^{1,2}(0,1)$, I've been able to show that $U$ is closed and that if an arbitrary sequence $\{u_n\}$ in $U$ which converges to $u$, then $u \in H^1(0,1)$. However, I am struggling to show that $u(0)=mu(1)$. My best attempt has been as follows:

Since $\int|u_n' - u'|^2dx \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we have that

$$  \int u_n' -  \int u' \le \int|u_n' - u'| \le \int|u_n' - u'|^2dx $$

then $$ (u_n(1)-mu_n(1))-(u(1)-u(0)) \rightarrow 0$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I've tried a variety of things after this point, and I can't seem to convince myself that $u(0)=mu(1)$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the Sobolev embedding the convergence is also uniform...

Comment: Your $U$ is the kernel of the functional $f$ on $H^1(0,1)$ defined via $f(u) = u(0) - m \, u(1)$. It also works for $m = 1$.

Comment: @gerw But would this linear functional be defined for functions that aren't defined at 0 and 1?

Comment: Due to the embedding $H^1(0,1) \subset C([0,1])$, all functions in $H^1(0,1)$ have well-defined values at $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to show that the endpoint evaluation functionals are continuous on $H^1$. You can use the Riesz representation for the functions, for example, where you find $g_0,g_1 \in H^1$ such that
$$
    f(0)= (f,g_0)+(f',g_0'),\;\; g\in H^1\\
    f(1)= (f,g_1)+(f',g_1'),\;\; g \in H^1.
$$
You know how to find $g_j$ because both satisfy
$$
               (f,g_j)+(f',g_j')=0,\;\;\; f\in\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(0,1).
$$
So $-g_j''+g_j = 0$, which means these functions are linear combinations of $e^{-x}$ and $e^{-x}$. $g_0$ vanishes at $1$ and $g_1$ vanishes at $0$, which leads to
$$
            g_0(x) = C_0\sinh(x-1),\;\; g_1(x)=C_1\sinh(x),
$$
where $C_j$ are constants chosen to normalized the functionals. For example,
\begin{align}
   (f,g_0)+(f',g_0')&=(f,g_0)+fg_0'|_{0}^{1}-(f,g_0') \\
                    &=fg'|_0^1=-fg'|_0\\
                    &=f(0)C_0\sinh(1).
\end{align}
So $C_0=1/\sinh(1)$ does the job.

The resulting functionals $\Phi_0$ and $\Phi_1$ are continuous linear functionals, and $U$ is the null space of $\Phi_0-m\Phi_1$, which makes it closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm confused, how exactly have you defined $\Phi_0$ and $\Phi_1$? It's not really clear. Could I not just do as gerw suggested above?

Comment: @KendrickEasley : What I've given you is the explicit Riesz representation with respect to the $H^1$ inner product. $f(0)=\Phi_0(f) = \langle f,C_0\sinh(x-1)\rangle_{H^1}= \langle f,C_0\sinh(x-1)\rangle_{L^2}+\langle f',C_0\cosh(x-1)\rangle_{L^2}$, which is the only kind of continuous linear functional on $H^1$.

Comment: @KendrickEasley : The problem comes down to showing that point evaluation is continuous on $H^1[0,1]$. By demonstrating the explicit construction of the pointwise evaluation as a continuous linear functional defined on a dense subspace, then you know that point evaluation makes sense on the entire space $H^1$. This is what you're missing to make your arguments work, and that's why I constructed the linear functional for you. Deriving the form of the functional is what I did for you, which I think is enlightening to see if you've never seen it.